# Best way of creating large bit arrays in Lua

Tags: c, lua, bit

I want to read a large binary file (1MB in size) into memory using Lua. The target device is mobile so I very much want to minimise the memory footprint.

From a quick look online it seems that Lua tables will use 16B for each sequential integer index (key) plus the space to store the value, which as I am storing binary data will hopefully only use 2 bits but lets just say 1 byte.

For 1e6 records that will be 1e6*17 =~ 17MB - which is huge!

From my brief reading it seems that I can use `userdata` to implement anything I want in C. I have not used C before but it seems that it would use

1b * 1e6 = 125kB

Shall i do this or have I got something very wrong / is there an easier way to do this.

Any advice or even name-calling for crappy calculations very much welcome :)

EDIT: Some interesting answers below about storing the data in a String (thanks!) and using bitwise ops. I just came accross an example in the PIL book (3rd edition pg293) that compares storing arrays of booleans in C so they use 3% of the mem. While this is cool and useful it may be overkill for me as the solutions below suggest I can fit in 1MB which is fine for me.

EDIT: Came across [this C blob impl](https://code.google.com/p/lua-blob/)

EDIT: Solution - I read the file contents into a String as suggested and as Im using 5.1 had to use a 3rd party bit op lib - I went with a pure Lua implementation [LuaBit](http://luaforge.net/projects/bit/). Thanks everyone!!

Comment: What do you want to do with the data once it's in the Lua environment?

Comment: use it to verify data by performing multiple hashes on incoming strings and checking the array (aka Bloom Filter) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea in Lua, it already hashes the strings, and if you only work with userdata, you can basically do nothing at all with it unless implement yourself. So you could skip the middle man and do everything in C.

Comment: thanks for reply. Well I wont actually be storing any strings - the bloom filter will represent words by flipping bits in the array - I will perform the hash(s) on the input string (char data) just so I know what bits in the array to check for validation. Make sense?

Comment: Every string that gets into the Lua environment is hashed. Doesn't matter if you store it. That means `"a" == "b"` actually compares hashes not strings. To hash a string, you have to read it, to read it with Lua, it has to get into the Lua environment and every time you get a substring this creates a new string which is hashed by Lua.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I will be performing a custom hash on the char data to check against the bloom filter - in my mind its irrelevant how strings are stored in Lua - this approach should work in any environment that supports chars and bit arrays as long as the same encoding is used for converting the chars to ints when performing the hash. Please tell me if I am missing somehthing

Comment: What you are missing is performance. I wouldn't tell you if you hadn't mentioned that its for a mobile environment. Hash once - ok fine, can't do without. Hash twice - not a good idea. Also Lua does not support Bit arrays, not many languages do (did you mean *Byte* arrays maybe?)

Comment: by an array of bits i mean a bool[]. All I want to do is dump the binary data "01010101..." into a data structure which i can then query in the form `is the bit at index x true` or something similar

Comment: Like I said before. Implement the hashing in C. If you want to process that further in Lua, you can still put the result in a userdata with a metatable that allows array-like access, even at bit level.

Comment: I really dont imagine that the overhead caused by a couple of hashes on a string in Lua is worth implementing in C! It will only be one string every few seconds.

Comment: You wrote about 1MB files in your question text ;)

Comment: sorry - thats of precomputed bloom filter data i.e. 1001010101 etc not string data! Thx for the comments :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store a big blob in Lua string, it will work with any binary data. Now the question is what you want to do with the data. In any way, you can use [string.byte](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.byte) to extract any individual byte, and use Lua's [bit32](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.7) library to get down to bits. (For Lua 5.1 and older, you'll either have to write your own C routines, or use third party package.)

Comment: You can extract individual bytes as numbers with `string.byte`. You can bitwise manipulations with the `bit32` library.

Comment: Great thanks. How do you store a blob in a string type using Lua - I cant see from googling!

Comment: I would look at the manual instead of googling :-) Use `file:read'*a'` to read the complete file or `file:read( n )` to read `n` bytes.

Comment: From the manual, it should be clear that in Lua the `string` type is a counted sequence of bytes. There are no content limitations on it like in many other languages.

Comment: I guess it would be better to store my binary data in the file rather than as a text file which is what im currently doing!

Answer (score 3):

You can store the data in a `string` and manipulate it with the string library and [Lua BitOp](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators)

Lua5.2's built-in bit32 library is preferred if available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read 1 MB into memory, you won't end up with 250 kB...

If you read the file into a Lua string, you end up with 1 MB, as Lua strings are just 8-bit clean bytes.

After that, you can process the data according its structure, using the perhaps the [struct library](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/).

Comment: if im reading from a txt file with UTF-8 encoding into a binary / bool array it would (please correct if Im wrong which I very well could be!). I imagine UTF-8 is used it does not care that its only storing binary data but would still use 8 bits per char uncompressed.

Comment: I see what you mean - I did the calc in the comment above mistakingly using 8 Bytes per char in a string, not 8 bits, thx

Comment: If your source is UTF-8 text, I would *definitely* consider that to be *binary*. Your second sentence does not make much sense to me: If there is "only binary data" in the file, how can it be UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: ah ok, so maybe this is my misunderstanding here. In my mind a text file usually uses an 8-bit encoding by default for english chars. Lets say we are using UTF-8, just because the actual char data is binary (meaning either a '0' or a '1') I would think it would still be using 8-bit chars to represent it. By this I mean a text file with contents "0101" >= 4x8bits (4 bytes) whereas a boolean array in memory could store this same data in 4 bits therefore the bit array should be approx 1/8 the size of the text file that is containing binary data. Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess if im reading the string data into lua and storing it as a string it will take up the exact same space yes - but I want to store convert the strings into actual byte data - so if I have "01010101" in the text file that would take up 1 byte of mem in Lua

Comment: Duplicate of my comment above but it would make a lot more sense if I had stored my raw binary data in the file instead of storing it as a text file!